# How to enable CDN with JClouds and Rackspace via Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles, jclouds

I'm attempting to use JCLouds via Clojure and would like to use the blobstore abstraction to create containers and then enable CDN serving on those containers. So far I haven't had much success.

I'm not a Java programmer so I'm not quite sure how to approach this, but it does appear [there is a method](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/ed2f18a1afe24c8987a15460f0be0275795fed28/apis/cloudfiles/src/main/java/org/jclouds/cloudfiles/CloudFilesClient.java#L66) that does what I need. That said, I'm unsure how to use that with `org.jclouds.blobstore2`.

What is the best way to achieve this in Clojure?

Comment: Hope this could be helpful http://clojure.org/java_interop

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I'm familiar with and use Java interop in my programs. However I'm not clear on where to even use the linked method in the context of `blobstore2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that via a Java example I was able to figure out the proper codepath for this in Clojure:

```
(defn- enable-cdn [bs container]
  (->
    (blobstore/blobstore-context bs)
    .unwrap
    .getApi
    (.enableCDN container)))
```

This will enable the CDN for a given container provided a valid blobstore instance. Maybe this will save someone else some time later.